# How to check on speed of the syncronizing progress?

Tags: blockchain, network

I've got the feeling my network syncronization sometimes stops. I'd like to keep an eye on incoming information. Preferably something that shows XXX Kb/s or that simply shows me the data that is coming in (`tail -f` style). Is there a way to keep tabs on this?

Comment: Synchronization is not about bandwidth, it is about disk and CPU speed.